# How should I use ES2020 in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-next, ecmascript-2020

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```json
    {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
          "es2018",
          "dom"
        ]
      }
    }
```

When I changed lib and target version from `es2018` to `es2020` it gives me below error:

> tsconfig.json(13,15): error TS6046: Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'esnext'.

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help

Comment: REMINDER: Safari on iOS devices is tied to the OS version. So anyone who hasn’t updated to iOS 13.4 or later will not be able to use ES2020 features. This is less than 1% of my users but unfortunately isn’t zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`es2020` support was [introduced in TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#es2020-for-target-and-module).

You must upgrade to [Angular 9.1](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-1-of-angular-now-available-typescript-3-8-faster-builds-and-more-eb292f989428) (or later) to use TypeScript 3.8.

Answer (score 4):

I was using `11.2.14` version of Angular, but still wasn't able to have `"target": "ES2020"` in `tsconfig.json`.

My build was failing on:

> Error: ./src/app/shared/validators/form.validators.ts 10:21
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:21)
> File was processed with these loaders:
>
> - ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js
> - ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js

> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> ...

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18204), the error is related to WebPack (my version 4.44.2). And support for `ES2020` will come with WebPack 5.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `es2020` was added as a target until Angular 9. So if you're on a version lower than that, I could see it not working.

`esnext` targets the latest supported features, so that should work very similarly.